# How to remove warning "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I make a php page in which i want to get data from database but when i run it gives me the warning "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource".

How i remove this warning?

Here is my code:

```
$strQuery1 = "select DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%m-%d-%Y') as transaction_date,sum(amount)as Amount from transactions where event_id='7' group by  DATE_FORMAT(transactions.transaction_date,'%m-%d-%Y')";
$result1 = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($strQuery1) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result1);
while($rs1=$result1->fetch_assoc()){    
    $res1[]=$rs1;                   
}
for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {
    foreach($res1 as $r){
        if($r['transaction_date']==$dates[$i]){
            $substrXML1= "<set value='" . $r['Amount'] ."' />";
            break;
        } else
           {
            $substrXML1= "<set value='0' />";
        }
    }
        $strXML1 .=$substrXML1;
}
    $strXML1.="</dataset>";
```

Comment: You remove it by *fixing* the error in your code! Notices aren't there to be "removed", they're there to point out *errors in your code*.

Comment: Your query does not return a mysql resource.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research or minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result1);
```

Comment: Some explanation would probably be good.

Answer (score -2):

May be this useful to you

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result1); //old
$rows = mysql_query($result1); //changed
while($rs1=mysql_fetch_array($rows))
or
while($rs1=$result1->fetch_assoc()){    
    $res1[]=$rs1;                   
}
```